# Applescript: How to get window count of a process in all spaces?

Tags: window, applescript

Updating Microsoft Office to the newest version caused a pop over error to occur every few hours.  "Mail could not be received at this time."  Only restarting the app makes the error go away.  Many people seem to have this problem with no resolution so I (a windows programmer) decided to write my first AppleScript.

First I tried to get the count of windows for Office:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to display dialog (count of windows)
```

returns 1 which is no good.  Does this mean the pop over dialog isn't considered a window by OSX?  Hmm. Seems unlikely.

Second I tried to get the window count from the process:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Outlook" to display dialog (count of windows)
```

returns 2.  Great.  Window 1 is the one I need and I write the script, run it, and works perfectly ... until I change from the space Outlook is in to a different space.  From the new space count of windows returns 0.  On further research it seems the spaces module is not included in Lion for AppleScript.

Anyone know how I can get a count of the process windows in all spaces?  Is there another way to detect the pop over?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to activate the application:

```
activate application "Microsoft Outlook"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
        if accessibility description of window 1 is "alert" then
            beep
            -- enter rest of your code
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: adayzdone - thanks for sharing the accessibility description, this is more efficient than the window count and check.  however, since the script is don on idle, when I activate Outlook it takes me from the space I'm working on to the space Outlook is in every 30 seconds or so.  seems odd that Apple has forced AppleScript to use spaces but removed the ability to access spaces in Lion.  There must be another way of doing this.